# BigInteger divide() method not working?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am dividing 2 `BigInteger` values

```
 N = 94400567826854724487909837398348327858277687772498043028143080274141357168982328449151039212940544180753206250882172215623025263699414679367833398858755440423828380162368132951103946930488990027827989933432181959968836035369641054955336867327681756681532771354933952141599581827698618739724580124555641633861

 e = 44598251142417535121365176389097472886004547620498587196637028250785621416609954924107228171779826812564450558386070863338405090708203920066925426522584172770629487602232360693706521107911895310319989921169318202224097739016252544913819802671755649536088117809831381940146419602124919706024152810967126830967
```

I am using this code to do so

```
System.out.println(e.divide(N));
```

and it prints 0. Is there something wrong with the divide method?

Comment: What did you expect as the result? This is equivalent to 4/9 which in integer arithmetic is also 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `e` value is smaller than your `N` value, and you're performing integer arithmetic, therefore you'll get a value of 0.

If you want non-integer division, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing a number x for a number that is about 2x. That means that result will be between 0 and 1. Since it is a Big **Integer**, the result will be a Big **Integer**, which will be 0.

If you want decimal values, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dividing them in wrong order, this works for me:

```
new BigInteger("94400567826854724487909837398348327858277687772498043028143080274141357168982328449151039212940544180753206250882172215623025263699414679367833398858755440423828380162368132951103946930488990027827989933432181959968836035369641054955336867327681756681532771354933952141599581827698618739724580124555641633861")
       .divide(new BigInteger("44598251142417535121365176389097472886004547620498587196637028250785621416609954924107228171779826812564450558386070863338405090708203920066925426522584172770629487602232360693706521107911895310319989921169318202224097739016252544913819802671755649536088117809831381940146419602124919706024152810967126830967"))
```

and yields... `2` (rounded 9/4 since `BigInteger` is used for integer values only).